# Transformer in series?

Tags: current-transformer

I've see people asking about transformers in series to get high voltage but what about transformers in series to get 6v, 600amps?
I'm at 3v 600 amps currently but I want to bump up the voltage without losing amps.

Answer (score 3):

It doesn't matter if it's "high voltage" — if you want to double the voltage, you can put two transformer windings in series. It's the same thing, whether you're talking about two 300V windings to get 600V, or two 3V windings to get 6V.

Comment: So you can increase voltage without sacrificing current in a transformer...?  Just seems contradictory to another answer I've seen.

Comment: @R.Johnson: Yes, as long as the transformer is large enough to handle the total power passing through it. If you have two 3V, 600A windings on a single transformer, it must have been designed to handle 3600 W. There's no problem with putting the two windings in series to get 6V @ 600A (or in parallel to get 3V @ 1200A). Otherwise, use two transformers -- put their primaries in parallel and their secondaries in series.

Comment: It DOES matter at "high voltages"  when the combined voltage exceeds the insulation rating of each individual transformer, breakdown is a problem. But that's not going to happen between 3 and 6V!)

Answer (score 0):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foPJFA.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Figure 2 shows a series connection of two transformers. The output voltage will be the sum (see note) of the individual output voltages at the rated current. Note: if the outputs are connected in anti-phase the voltages will cancel out to zero.

Figure 3 shows the parallel connection of two transformers. In this case the current is doubled but the voltage remains the same. If the outputs are connected in anti-phase there will be a very big bang somewhere. At these currents arc-flash protective clothing may be required.

It's not relevant to your question about series connection, but if you ever need to check the phase of two windings before parallel connection then:

- Connect the two ground legs.
- Power up.
- Check for voltage on each secondary winding. If both are the same proceed.
- Measure the voltage between the two 'hot' legs. If it's zero then they're in phase. If it's double the reading from the previous step then they're out of phase and you need to reverse one winding.